# Apache Karaf auto-adding library to jre.properties during build?

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf

I have a library that relies on exporting a `sun.reflect` package from JRE.properties. During testing I have been manually adding this. What can I do to ensure this is automatically added within Apache Karaf?

Answer (score 0):

Changes to the etc/jre.properties requires a container restart. If you are deploying this Karaf instance inside a Linux container (aka Docker), you would simply include this change as part of the linux container image build.

However, if you are deploying into a Virtual Machine environment, you'd want to make this part of your organization's custom build of Karaf. I suggest using a Maven project with the Assembly plugin to apply all your organization's changes-- ldap, security, ssl certs, etc/jre.properties... etc. It would then create a new .tar.gz or .zip file that and you would deploy your app into the modified Karaf instance.

There is an example in the HYTE Runtime build here:

[HYTE Runtime](https://github.com/hyteio/runtime/tree/master/hyte-runtime)

Technically, you could leverage the feature deployment mechanism to deploy an updated file, but this won't cause the Karaf instance to restart.